# Minimal bitstring set union with shifts algorithm

Tags: algorithm, set, bit-manipulation, sequence-alignment

I'm looking for an algorithm to solve, or at least a proper name for the following problem:

---

I have a set ***B*** of bitstrings. The algorithm should find a minimal (defined as "having fewest bits set") bitstring ***S*** such that:

> For all ***b*** in ***B***, there exists a shift ***N*** (in [ℤ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer)) such that `(S << N) & b == b`.

---

If it helps, each *b* fits in a machine word, and |*B*| is on the order of a couple hundred.

---

I think we can assume (without loss of generality) that the LSB of *S* and each *b* is 1.

This looks to me like some kind of [multiple sequence-alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_sequence_alignment) problem.

If we can find each *N<sub>i</sub>* for each *b<sub>i</sub>* in *B* (*i* = 1 .. |*B*|), it looks like *S* is just the bitwise-or across all (*b<sub>i</sub>* >> *N<sub>i</sub>*).

My intuition is, the first step is to remove every *b* from *B* for which there exists another bitstring *c* in *B* and some shift *M* such that `b & (c << M) == b`. What's next?

Comment: The shift amount being in ℤ is interesting, does that mean that a negative left shift acts as a right shift?

Comment: I think this is equal to ["Shortest common supersequence problem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_common_supersequence_problem) for a set of strings.  It is NP-Hard in general, but for your particular case it should not be too hard to solve it.

Comment: @harold Yes, negative left shifts act as right shifts.

Comment: @EvgenyKluev Thanks, this does look related to that problem. The main difference is that a 1 in the supersequence can match a 0 in the set of sequences to be matched. I suppose the supersequence could consist of Xs and 0s, where X means "don't care" and 0 means "must have a 0".

Comment: Another important difference to the "shortest common supersequence problem" which tries to minimize the length, is that AlliedEnvy tries to minimize the number of bits that are set to 1.

Answer (score 0):

My specific instance of *B* was small enough to be amenable to brute force, with a few tricks to prune the search.

With the following functions already defined,

- [`snoob`](http://www.hackersdelight.org/hdcodetxt/snoob.c.txt), returns the next-highest number with the same number of bits set (as defined in Hacker's Delight fig. 2-1 (or originally, HAKMEM item 175))
- [`popcount`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight), returns the number of 1-bits in its argument
- [`clz`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight), returns the number of consecutive zeroes in the most-significant end of its argument

Pseudocode for my solution is as follows:

```
min_ones = max popcount(b) for b in B
max_ones = popcount(~0)

for i = 0 .. |B|-1:
    while !(B[i] & 1): B[i] >>= 1

found_ones = false
for ones = min_ones .. max_ones:
    if found_ones: break
    for S = (1 << ones)-1; clz(S) > 0; S = snoob(S):
        if !(S & 1): continue
        for b in B:
            found = false
            for N = 0 .. clz(b) - clz(S):
                if (S >> N) & b == b:
                    found = true
                    break
            if !found: break
         if found:
             print(S)
             found_ones = true
```

The first loop shifts right each *b* so its LSB is 1; this allows us to only use right shifts for N later.

The loop over *S* starts with the smallest number with `ones` bits set; the loop stop condition isn't quite correct, but it works well enough for my purposes.

The loop over *N* starts with the LSB of *S* and *b* aligned, and then goes to the most-significant one-bits of *S* and *b* aligned.

---

For now, I'm leaving the question as unsolved to see if a proper non-brute-force solution comes around, or until someone says the problem is NP-hard.